# PyQt5 QTableWidget создать обработчики для ячеек в цикле

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

Есть примерно такой код:

```
i=0
for x in range(5):
    self.item = QTableWidgetItem('Ячейка')
    self.tableWidget.setItem(i,0, self.item)
    i+=1
```

Как для события клик по ячейке запрограммировать разные 
обработчик/обработчики (методы в классе)?

Пытаюсь что-нибудь придумать, пока ничего не получается.
У класса `QTableWidgetItem` похоже вообще нет никаких сигналов.

Comment: а что конкретнее вам нужно?

Comment: прочитайте пожалуйста мой комментарий к первому ответу...

Answer (score 2):

```
from PyQt5 import Qt
import sys
import re


class MainWindow(Qt.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setRowCount(5)
        self.setColumnCount(5)
        self.cellClicked.connect(self.row_column_clicked)
        for x, i in enumerate(d):
            self.setItem(x, 0, Qt.QTableWidgetItem('Ячейка: {}'.format(i)))

    def row_column_clicked(self):
        row = self.currentRow()
        col = self.currentColumn()
        value = self.item(row, col)
        if value:
            value = value.text()
            print(d[com.sub("", value)])   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = {"5": "тест 0", '20': 'текст 1', '66': 'текст 2', '11': 'текст 3', '777': 'текст 4'}
    com = re.compile("[^\d]")
    app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: спасибо за код, но передавать значение через имя ячейки нельзя. Я вот тут нашел у класса QTableWidgetItem метод setData - возможно можно использовать его QTableWidgetItem::setData(int role, const QVariant &value)?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите создать что-то такое:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt
import sys

class MainWindow(Qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        Qt.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.tableWidget = Qt.QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tableWidget)

        self.tableWidget.cellClicked.connect(self.row_column_clicked)

        for x in range(5):
            self.button = Qt.QPushButton('Изменить... {}'.format(x), self)
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(x, 1, self.button)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(x, 0, Qt.QTableWidgetItem('Ячейка: {},{}'.format(x, 0)))
            self.button.clicked.connect(lambda state, w=self.tableWidget.cellWidget(x,1), r=x, c=1: self.button_pushed(w, r, c))

    def button_pushed(self, w, r, c): 
        print("Clicked ячейки: ", r, ", ", c)
        print("В этой ячейке : `{}`".format(w.text()))

    def row_column_clicked(self):    
        row = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
        col = self.tableWidget.currentColumn()
        value = self.tableWidget.item(row, col)
        if value:
            value = value.text()
            print("Clicked ячейки: ", row, ", ", col)
            print("В этой ячейке : `{}`".format(value))
        else:
            print("Clicked ячейки: ", row, ", ", col)
            print("Ячейка ПУСТАЯ")            

app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
w   = MainWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем - столбец только один первый. И значения переменных должны быть привязаны или к id в базе данных или например быть значениями словаря dict = {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'} и далее for x in dict. Думаю currentRow() и currentColumn() тут не подойдут так как id в базе могут идти не по порядку

Comment: Нужно чтобы при клике по ячейке выводился id или имя ключа из словаря